# Error android- java Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android

I am getting this error when i am inflating another activity on button click of first activity.I am also Passing the data between the activities.when the data is not being passed then it works fine and am able to view the second activity.the data i am passing is the content of text box from the first activity of integer type.Kindly lemme know where am i going wrong.

code for Activity1.class

```
public void onClick(View v)

    {

        try
        {
    Log.i("MyActivity", "Entered OnClick()");
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int value;
    value=Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());
    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("param1",value);
//  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RoutePath.class);
    myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
     startActivity(myIntent);
        }
         catch(Exception e)
            {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

and Activity2.class

```
public class RoutePath extends MapActivity {

GeoPoint gp1;

GeoPoint gp2;

GeoPoint srcGeoPoint;

GeoPoint destGeoPoint;

double distance;

int value=0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{   



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    value = bundle.getInt("param1",0);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.myMapView1);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

//and then the other code.......

}
```

and the stack trace

```
03-21 15:44:39.276: WARN/System.err(3337): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 15:44:39.286: WARN/System.err(3337):     at com.nautilus.RoutePath.Welcome.onClick(Welcome.java:50)
03-21 15:44:39.306: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
03-21 15:44:39.331: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
03-21 15:44:39.335: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)
03-21 15:44:39.348: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
03-21 15:44:39.355: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-21 15:44:39.355: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-21 15:44:39.385: WARN/System.err(3337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 15:44:39.396: WARN/System.err(3337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
```

Comment: On what line do you get an Exception? Or is it in platform code?

Comment: Ok for the stack trace, you need to show us the code inside RoutePath.Welcome

Comment: Just click on the line 2 of your stacktrace in LogCat and you'll find the error line in your code. Probably, it's `value=Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());` where range is null? :) I wonder

Comment: see the update in my response

Answer (score 1):

Some advices :

- Read and provide a stack trace inside your question, it will be very helpfull.
- Use `this` instead of `v.getContext()` in your `Intent` constructor
- `Integer.parseInt()` will throw `NumberFormatException` if your variable `range` (which is an `EditText` I assume) returns a empty string, so maybe you should test the result of `range.getText().toString()`.

---

EDIT :

- Do you affect a value to the `range` variable ? Something like
   `range = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.range)`

Comment: i did all the possible modifications that u suggested but it is nt wrkng...i am able to enter the onClick method ..it seems there is an error in the oncREATE METHOD OF SECOND ACTIVITY.

Comment: all ? So where is the stack trace ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
int value;
value=Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("param1",value);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RoutePath.class);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Try

```
int value;
value=Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RoutePath.class);
myIntent.putExtra("param1",value);
```

Comment: Then you should provide a stack trace of the Exception you are getting.

Comment: its on the line whwre i retreive the value of editText n convert it into int  value=Integer.parseInt(range.getText().toString());

Comment: Then put a breakpoint on that line, and see that range is null. So it must not be initialized properly ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's no view with id `R.id.myMapView1` on `R.layout.main` layout. But what about providing a stack trace?